# UnassignedReferenceException: The variable rb of Player has not been assigned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm really new to Unity, and so I was trying a few things out. So, I read about how to make a player jump, but when I use the code, the error in the title shows up.

[image]
So, this is my unity screen, and I know i need to assign Rb under Player (Script) to the Rigidbody 2D, but it doesn't show up in the list.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. You've declared `rb` as a variable of type `RigidBody2D`, but have not assigned a value to that variable. You can't use a variable that has not been assigned.

Comment: For `RigidBody2d` not showing in the list, try grabbing your `player` from hierarchy and drop it in `RigidBody2D` slot. It should work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick fix for you

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    void Start() 
    { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your fix, I get this error and variants of it. "Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(16,12): error CS1501: No overload for method 'AddForce' takes 3 arguments"

Comment: Just replace rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); with rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime)); Remember this is a quick fix, you can read more about it here :https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

Answer (score -1):

Addforce must have two arguments only. try this instead.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbidy2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * sidewaysForce , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.left * sidewaysForce , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the lines with yours and I don't get any more errors and I'm able to assign the Rigidbody2D to rb. The only problem is that player doesn't move if I press a or d.

Comment: you have to change that also. rb.AddForce(transform.left * forwardForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

Comment: Unity gives an error saying there's nothing called transfrom.left

EDIT: I fixed it by doing -transform.right

Comment: ok my bad then the left should be -transform.right.